# HTML Purifier Special Character Encodings

Tags: htmlpurifier

I was wondering how can I stop html purifier from turning my `&` signs to `&amp;` and into `&#038;` instead?

Comment: I just want the `&#038;` instead.

Comment: @jleedev Sorry wrong code its fixed. Good looking

Comment: At least answer your own question to help people with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

It should be fine to str_replace &amp; into &#038; after the purification.